# Debugging Google App Engine's SDC - What does USER_NOT_HOSTED mean?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am having a issue using Google's SDC (Secure Data Connector) with my Google App Engine application (my app is unable to get data from within my network but using a Google Docs spreadsheet I can get the data).

So I found this troubleshooting info: http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/docs/debug.html. and as suggested I added the debug header to url fetch and received the debug information back but I am not sure what it means:

sdc_routing : Internet
sdc_internet_routing : USER_NOT_HOSTED

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means the user you are using to access SDC resources is NOT a valid user in that domain.

a company foobar.com may give access to certain users to access resources thru SDC.
and foobar.com registers all such users with Google thru the foobar.com domain administration page.

this user that you are using is NOT one of the users that foobar.com has given access to.

you can also provide your domain name, username etc through the domain administration page on google.com and get better help faster..this issue should be quite easy to troubleshoot.

hope this helps.